# How do I `pass` the Type from one class to another?

Tags: flutter, dart, types

Please look at the sample below

```dart
class Foo<T> {
  Type get type => T;
}

class Bar<T> {}

void main() {
  final foo = Foo<String>();
  final Type type = foo.type;
  final bar = Bar<type>(); // <= error on [type]: 
  ///The name 'type' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument - line 10
}
```

I'm aware of the basic approach below, but requires to know in advance the `Type`

```
Bar fromFoo<T>(Foo<T> foo) => Bar<T>();
```

***what is the correct way to create a `Bar` of the same Type of `Foo`
without knowing the Type in advance?***

I couldn't find the answer I'm looking for [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system) or [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/sound-problems)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @Jhakiz [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65479449/how-do-i-pass-the-type-from-one-class-to-another/65480052#65480052) does solve the question,
but things get complicated when you need to use the Type in function inside `Bar`

```dart
class Bar<T> {
  void call(T arg) => print('$arg');
}
```

I came up with a workaround, it might come handy to some

```dart
/// `set up`

mixin TypeDelegate<T> {}

mixin TypeFactoryMixin<T> {
  TypeDelegate useTypeFactory(TypeFactoryDelegate typeFactory) =>
      typeFactory<T>();
}

mixin TypeFactoryDelegate {
  TypeDelegate<T> call<T>();
}

abstract class TypeBase<T> with TypeFactoryMixin<T> implements TypeDelegate<T> {
}

/// `example`

class Foo<T> extends TypeBase<T> {
  Type ofType() => T;
}

class Bar<T> extends TypeBase<T> {
  Bar();
  Type ofType() => T;
  factory Bar.fromTypeBase(TypeBase<T> typeBase) =>
      typeBase.useTypeFactory(BarFactory()) as Bar;
}

class BarFactory implements TypeFactoryDelegate {
  Bar<T> call<T>() => Bar<T>();
}

void main() {
  final foo = Foo<String>();

  final bar = Bar.fromTypeBase(foo);

  print('foo of type: ${foo.ofType()}');
  print('bar of type: ${bar.ofType()}');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Francesco Iapicca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9836706/francesco-iapicca) Try this snippet code by passing the `Foo` type in `Bar`'s constructor:

```
class Foo<T> {
  Type get type => T;
}

class Bar {
  final Type t;
  Bar({this.t});
}

void main() {
  final foo = Foo<String>();
  final bar = Bar(t: foo.type);
}
```

Note that the type of `t` variable in `Bar` is the same with `type` from `Foo`